# Applet error ClassNotFoundException; Reload works

Tags: java, applet, classnotfoundexception

I browse to an html page with an applet tag. The applet tag refernces two signed jars. I receive two Security Warning dialogs indicating the revocation status cannot be checked, accept the risk, and click Run for both of them. The browser displays an error gif that says "Error: click for details. I click.

The Application Error dialog says ClassNotFoundException and the name of the class, and displays three options. I click (1) Details and see the Java Console with the menu but no errors. I click (2) Ignore with no apparent effect. I click (3) reload and the applet loads and runs properly.

I have the latest java security update. This happens in Chrome and FireFox. I've signed the certificate using a Certificate from my Acitve Directory Certificate Server, I added the site to my list of trusted sites, and the CA certificate to the list of CA certs in the Java Control panel.

I'm glad it works in the end but would like to avoid having to click Reload each time. Can anyone suggest what I might do differently?

Comment: Out of curiosity do you have `Trusted-Library: true` to the manifest file in the jars?

Comment: I didn't but do now. Unfortunately, no change. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I've tested using Windows 7, java build 1.7.0_17-b02 (x64) and Windows 8.0 build 1.7.0_51-b13 and the results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

General suggestion is to not use what is all but a completely deprecated technology (applets).

More specifically, it is likely a browser problem in how the JVM and class-loader is working with signed JARs. Initially it would not load because it could not find/verify a registry for certificate revocations. So the class did not load. On re-load, it picked up on the 'ignore' the issue problem so it then loaded the class.

This seems related to a similar question that suggests verifying file-naming as well: [ClassNotFoundException only if JAR is signed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158789/classnotfoundexception-only-if-jar-is-signed)